# voltage rating for RF filter components

Tags: electronics, equipment-design, filter

I want to design a PCB for a diplexer for Satellite operations. I want to use SMD capacitors and possible inductors to get some experience with soldering SMD components. What should the voltage rating be for the components? Satellite operations are usually low power, 5 to 15 watts, but RF filters should be able to handle 100 watts or more.

Comment: that's going to depend on your filter topology. Can you provide more detail?

Comment: Here's a design that handles up to 10 watts, according to the author.  Maybe it can give you some ideas.  http://kw4fb.com/micro-diplexer/

Answer (score 1):

Calculate of simulate the RF volts across your filter caps .Remember that The voltage rating of most caps falls with applied frequency .You have your RF volts and your cap value so calc your ripple current and check the ratings .This is why the voltage rating of the caps will be higher than what you think .